# Laravel - How to submit URL in form input

Tags: url, input, laravel-5.4

How to submit a URL in form in Laravel, i'm using input type text to store, but Laravel prevent me to submit url to database, it return me a 406 error, here is my code:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=>['staff\StaffUserController@update', $user->id], 'class'=>'add_user_form', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
!! Form::text('url', $user->fblink, ['class' => 'color_grey3', 'placeholder' => '  ']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

How to make Laravel approve the URL submit as a input?

Comment: Ir `$user->fblink` is a data that you can get from database, why not send the id and then do a query to get fblink?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte no, i mean $user->fblink is a URL, and when on the server with SSL protected, the form cannot submit, it return me a 406 not accept error